# Solving limit Lim ar r goes to zero $ 1/e^{1/r^{2}}.r $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

What is

$$\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{e^{1/r^{2}}\cdot r}  
\end{equation*}$$

as $r\to 0?$

I tried using L'hopital's rule once, then I used the series for the exponential and the limit turned out to be zero

However, I am not confident enough. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: You mean $\displaystyle\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{r}e^{\frac{1}{r^2}}$ ?

Comment: You want to solve $\lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{r} \rm{e}^{1/r^2}$ and $\lim_{r \uparrow 0} \frac{1}{r} \rm{e}^{1/r^2}$?

Comment: Use the substitution $\frac{1}{r^2}=t$ , you can easily see where it goes.

Comment: @Ritz none of them .both quantities are in denominator

Comment: If it's $\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}{r}$, you can use L'Hospital's rule, because both numerator and denominator tend to 0

Comment: @Alex l'hospital aint work here

Comment: $\frac{0}{0}$??

Comment: @K.Dutta , is the edit what represents your fraction?

Comment: @Mann yes true thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to find $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{r\cdot e^{r^{-2}}}.$$ Rewrite at $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{r^{-1}}{e^{r^{-2}}}$$ and apply L'Hospital's rule as you said.

You get $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{-r^{-2}}{e^{r^{-2}}\cdot (-2)r^{-3}}=
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{r}{2e^{r^{-2}}}.$$ The numerator goes to $0$ and the denominator goes to $+\infty$. So, the whole fractions goes to $0$, regardless of whether $r\rightarrow 0^+$, or $r\rightarrow 0^-$.

Your answer seems right.